# Select after insert statement executed in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I want to know how should I select data after it has been inserted in database using hibernate.

Comment: Can you clarify? What is your need exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to start with the [HQL (Hibernate Query Language) reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html).